# Fastboot not showing device, adb finds it

Tags: linux, fastboot, oneplus-two

I'm having issues trying to get Fastboot to find my device. 
Interestingly ADB finds it.
My specs are below:

- Computer: Ubuntu 14.04
- Phone: One Plus Two Oxygen OS 2.1.1

  ```
  james@james-Aspire-3830TG:~$ adb devices
  List of devices attached 
  3778baee    device

  james@james-Aspire-3830TG:~$ fastboot devices
  james@james-Aspire-3830TG:~$
  ```

Comment: If this is better for ask Ubuntu  please let me know /  move it - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are in fastboot mode before using fastboot devices for device to show up.

If it still does not show up, looks like you don't have the fastboot driver properly installed.

Use the  following to install fastboot drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-fastboot
```

If the repository isn't available add it using: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools && sudo apt-get update`

Note: The commands are for distributions using apt. Specifcally Ubuntu and variants. Commands for others may vary.